# How do I create a multilevel index from column names?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want to create an index as part of a multilevel index from data that is embedded in a column name. This question is much easier to show than describe. This is what my original data looks like:

```
d = {'time':[0,1,2], 'part_0_hits': [100,200,300], 'part_1_hits': [25,50,75]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to create a new index called 'part' that has the part numbers in the column names. The result needs to look like this:

```
d2 = {'time':[0,1,2,0,1,2], 'part':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 'hits':[100,200,300,25,50,75]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

I would put the tables in here, but I'm not sure how to do the markup. Here's a snapshot of my iPython notebook with the dataframes displayed:

[image]

There must be an elegant way of doing this, but I can't seem to find it. If I can get it to look like the above dataframe, I can use set_index to create the multilevel index...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pd.melt for this

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["time"],var_name="part", value_name="hits")
df['part'] = df['part'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

You get

```
    time    part    hits
0    0      0       100
1    1      0       200
2    2      0       300
3    0      1       25
4    1      1       50
5    2      1       75
```

Comment: Wonderful! This is close. I should have included a more complex starting point though. My real data has many columns per part. So if I have part_0_hits and also part_0_size along with part_1_hits and part_1_size for columns, can I still use pd.melt in a similar way? Thanks again!

Comment: @Noise in the street, It would work on any number of columns. Once you have selected you id variable (time in this case), melt would unpivot the rest of the columns and return variable and value